# Detect all old browsers equal to IE9 and lower

Tags: php, cross-browser, compatibility

I want to detect old browsers with PHP and send them to a more compatible site. I want to detect from IE8 and lower but that's just Internet Explorer. I suppose Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc have versions that are equal to IE9.

So my question would be what would be the best way to detect all old browsers that are equale to IE9 and lower.

Comment: You need to first know which browser version your webpage supports. After you have done this you will find many questions here on SO that state how to retrieve browser version using PHP.

Comment: Well it would take a lot of time to test all old versions of other browsers that why I wanted to know the versions of chrome, firefox, safari that would be equal to IE9

Comment: I can say for a fact that no browser other than IE9 is going to be equal to IE9. You'll want to check for features, not browser versions.

Answer (score 3):

There are no "versions of chrome, firefox, safari that would be equal to IE9" - you can check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) at the very most.

The best approach is to check features client-side via [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

You can use [conditional comments](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/) to detect certain versions of IE, though.